# Comparison of end-to-end encryption and TLS

Tags: encryption, symmetric, tls, data-privacy

I am writing a comparison paper about security of electronic communication and I want to compare end-to-end encryption and TLS by giving two examples such as Whatsapp and Facebook Messenger. However, I am not sure if this is a valid comparison.

If they are comparable solutions to this problem, how should I compare them? In which aspects are they superior?

If they are not, which two solutions can I compare? I am new in this topic but I am willing to learn.

I would be grateful for any kind of suggestions.

Comment: Well, the idea of TLS is to be node-to-node (e.g. client-server, server-client) and for end-to-end for it to be client-to-client.

Comment: So, does it make sense to compare them? I hope this is not an apple and orange comparison. Can I compare in terms of for example integrity, speed, viability etc ?

Comment: I think it totally makes sense to compare them. A lot of people are not aware of the differences.

Comment: I suggest you could compare email encryption end-to-end with PGP or S/MIME with node-to-node transport encryption as in SMTPS or SMTP with TLS.